# Making an iOS authorised Google API call

Tags: ios, google-api, access-token

I have integrated Google Sign-in into my iOS app and retrieved the access tokens after signing in. I am now wanting to make authorised API calls to Google, but am unsure how to do this to include the token.
Can someone please share some code that I can use to include this?
Thanks a lot,
Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have logged in and acquired tokens, you create service instances and then attach an "authorizer." Google's Objective-C client supports quite a few services: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Here is a sample using Google+:

**Obj-C (with ARC enabled)**

```
GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

# set an authorizer with your tokens
[plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];

# submit authenticated queries, assuming your scopes & tokens are legit
GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                     collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];


[plusService executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                            NSError *error) {
               //  ... your callback ...
       }];
```

**Swift**

```
var plusService = GTLServicePlus()
plusService.retryEnabled = true

# set an authorizer with your tokens
plusService.authorizer = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().authentication

if let plusQuery = GTLQueryPlus.queryForPeopleListWithUserId("me",
                collection: kGTLPlusCollectionVisible) as? GTLPlusQuery {
    // execute the query
    plusService.executeQuery(plusQuery) { (ticket: GTLServiceTicket!,
                                           peopleFeed: GTLPlusPeopleFeed!,
                                           error: NSError!) -> Void in
        // ... your callback ...
    }
}
```

[There is a sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample/) of using the Google Obj-C API client with YouTube specifically. Check out line [229](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample/YouTubeSampleWindowController.m#229) in `YouTubeSampleWindowController.m` for setting up your `GTLServiceYouTube` object, and line [261](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample/YouTubeSampleWindowController.m#261) for an example of using it with a `GTLQueryYouTube` object.

There are also some nice [CocoaDocs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/iOS-GTLYouTube/0.0.4/Classes/GTLQueryYouTube.html). [This method](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/iOS-GTLYouTube/0.0.4/Classes/GTLQueryYouTube.html#//api/name/queryForSubscriptionsListWithPart:) is probably what you're after.

Comment: Would you be able to link in which page you got this from? Ideally, can you provide an equivilent for YouTube? I followed the link and when I click on the services it just takes me to their developer's homepage. Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people, and a bit of my own code for the Swift example. There is also a sample with the YouTube API here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FYouTubeSample

Comment: Added some links and code references for YouTube. Hope those help!

Comment: I found this and think it's the right thing https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&_h=10& . Just when I try it I get the unauthorised request error. I'm trying to retrieve my subscribers number.

Comment: Are you trying it from the APIs explorer, or your app? From the APIs explorer you will have to attach OAuth2 credentials. From your app, if it still isn't working, inspect the network traffic between your device and Google and make sure the "Authorization" header is making it onto your calls.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in the end with `BAHYouTubeOAuth`, available [here](https://cocoapods.org/?q=BAHYouTubeOAuth).
I spoke with the creator of this and he said that changes were up and coming in regards to better token handling.
If it hasn't been changed officially, check out my amendments [here](https://mega.nz/#!c1w2QbLQ!RyLYHQ4ZJsW1wh9mzliPOsMf9vlglmP13FlfkoYkbdU)